# Как разместить блок <div> вдоль верхней границы карты?

Tags: google-maps-api

Как по верху карты (встроенной в сайт) разместить блок `<div>` с произвольной информацией?

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него свой код, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/150283)

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный:
`position: relative` у родительского элемента,
`position: absolute` у дочернего элемента.

Хотя сложно понять вопрос без кода...

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Layer: Styling</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });

  // [START snippet-load]
  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
  // [END snippet-load]

  // [START snippet-style]
  // Set the stroke width, and fill color for each polygon
  map.data.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'green',
    strokeWeight: 1
  });
  // [END snippet-style]
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Документация Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-style)**. 
Или же так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GeoRSS Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 49.496675, lng: -102.65625}
  });

  var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss'
  });
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?" async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Документация Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-georss)**.

Ещё пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directly accessing Street View data</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
    <div id="pano" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
    <script>
/*
 * Click the map to set a new location for the Street View camera.
 */

var map;
var panorama;

function initMap() {
  var berkeley = {lat: 37.869085, lng: -122.254775};
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));

  // Set up the map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: berkeley,
    zoom: 16,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  // Set the initial Street View camera to the center of the map
  sv.getPanorama({location: berkeley, radius: 50}, processSVData);

  // Look for a nearby Street View panorama when the map is clicked.
  // getPanoramaByLocation will return the nearest pano when the
  // given radius is 50 meters or less.
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    sv.getPanorama({location: event.latLng, radius: 50}, processSVData);
  });
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });

    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Street View data not found for this location.');
  }
}

    </script>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Документация Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service)**. 
Или же самостоятельно выберите из **[предложенных Гугл примеров](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)**.